# conditionally display columns in Django admin based on filtered queryset

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to hide some columns in the django admin when all the values in that column are null. I have tried using `get_list_display` but the queryset returned is the one *before* being filtered, therefore it's no use.

```py
def get_list_display(self, request):
    result = super().get_list_display(request)
    # remove some columns when there's no data, to save space
    if not any(d.node_type for d in super().get_queryset(request)):
        result = (r for r in result if r not in {'node_type', 'mesh_layer'})
    return result
```

It's just occured to me that the value of `list_display` is probably affecting the final query itself, is there some way to filter the columns shown *after* the query but before displaying the final result?